# How to Interpolate through ModelBuilder?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, modelbuilder, interpolation, spline

I would like to create an iterated interpolation tool through ModelBuilder. I have an excel file containing different columns and each column represents a data that will be interpolated using Spline Tool. How can I do this through ModelBuilder? I am using ArcGIS 10.

[image]

Image contains point data with lat/long and sample# are the columns to be interpolated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following model will achieve what you require:

[image: Iterate over fields]

- Your screen shot shows fields SAMPLE 1 to 9 so set the *For* iterator to this.
- Convert your lat/long into an event layer which feeds into the Spline tool. Note the use of in-line substitution to create the field name that will be the Z field. The same is used to create unique output raster names.

Comment: Hi, Hornbydd:

May I know where is the connecting arrow between "FOR" and "Sheet1$ event"?

Comment: There is no connection, the iterator controls the whole model and is generating a variable called value which you use inline substitution to make use of it.

Comment: Hi, Hornbydd: I tried the model you posted and I got similar range of values from SAMPLE1.tif to SAMPLE9.tif. I am not sure what went wrong.

Comment: Did you ensure you Z value field was set to: SAMPLE%Value%